# Using R tidyr pivot_wide to get wide-form data from multiple column names and values

Tags: r, tidyr

How can I use [tidyr pivot_wide](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_wider.html) to convert this data frame from long form to wide form? I tried applying the examples on the docs page, but I must be missing something.

**Data Frame**

```
id <- c(1,1,2,2,3,3)
filename <- c('file1a.txt', 'file1b.txt', 
              'file2a.txt', 'file2b.txt', 
              'file3a.txt', 'file3b.txt')
val <- c(832, 834, 221, 878, 2, 19)

df1 <- data.frame(id, filename, val)
view(df1)
```

| id | filename | val |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | file1a.txt | 832 |
| 1 | file1b.txt | 834 |
| 2 | file2a.txt | 221 |
| 2 | file2b.txt | 878 |
| 3 | file3a.txt | 2 |
| 3 | file3b.txt | 19 |

**Desired Output**

| id | filename1 | filename2 | val1 | val2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | file1a.txt | file1b.txt | 832 | 834 |
| 2 | file2a.txt | file2b.txt | 221 | 878 |
| 3 | file3a.txt | file3b.txt | 2 | 19 |

**Failed Attempts**

```
df_wide <- pivot_wider(data = df1, 
                       id_cols = id, 
                       values_from = c("filename", "val"))
view(df_wide)
```

| id | filename_ | val_ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1:2 | c(832,834) |
| 2 | 3:4 | c(221,878) |
| 3 | 5:6 | c(2,19) |

```
df_wide <- pivot_wider(data = df1, 
                       id_cols = id, 
                       names_from = c("filename", "val"), 
                       values_from = c("filename", "val"))
view(df_wide)
```

| id | filename_file1a.txt_832 | filename_file1b.txt_834 | filename_file2a.txt_221 | ...etc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | file1a.txt | file1b.txt | NA | ...etc |
| 2 | NA | NA | file2a.txt | ...etc |
| 3 | NA | NA | NA | ...etc |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need a row sequence

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(data.table)
df1 %>%
    mutate(cn = rowid(id)) %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = cn, values_from = c(filename, val), names_sep="")
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 5
#     id filename1  filename2   val1  val2
#  <dbl> <chr>      <chr>      <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1 file1a.txt file1b.txt   832   834
#2     2 file2a.txt file2b.txt   221   878
#3     3 file3a.txt file3b.txt     2    19
```

---

Or do a group by `row_number`

```
df1 %>%
    group_by(id)
    mutate(cn = row_number()) %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = cn, values_from = c(filename, val), names_sep="")
```

---

If we need not use `%>%`, specify the `data` as the `mutate`d original dataset, with an added column 'cn' based on the sequence of 'id'

```
pivot_wider(mutate(df1, cn = rowid(id)), 
   names_from = cn, values_from = c(filename, val), names_sep="")
```

Comment: I want to implement it without the pipes, but I am getting stuck; is there a solution without pipes

Comment: @a11 can you please check the update.  Is that what you have in mind

Comment: @a11 wouldn't the one without %>% confuses you.

Answer (score 1):

A `data.table` option with `dcast`

```
> dcast(setDT(df1), id ~ rowid(id), value.var = c("filename", "val"))
   id filename_1 filename_2 val_1 val_2
1:  1 file1a.txt file1b.txt   832   834
2:  2 file2a.txt file2b.txt   221   878
3:  3 file3a.txt file3b.txt     2    19
```

Comment: oh this is much better to me, but I already accepted the other answer. I upvoted it though, and thank you

Comment: @a11 No worries and thank your upvote :)